# Regular expressions in Javascript (4 number and 1 letter)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for a password. This password must have 4 numbers followed by 1 letter.

For example:

> 1234a

My code isn´t working:

```
var txt = new RegExp("/([0-9]{4}[a-z]{1})");
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

if (txt.test(pass)) {
     alert("OK");
} else {
     alert("No OK");
}
```

Comment: You need start and end anchors.  Try this: `^\d{4}[A-Za-z]$`.

Comment: Even if it is homework, the question is at least about evaluating code that the OP has written, and not just asking us to give the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `new RegExp` you don't need to have `/` at the start and end of the string you pass to it. Use this:

```
var txt = new RegExp("([0-9]{4}[a-z]{1})");
```

And if you want to pass any modifiers to the regular expression using `new RegExp` then pass them as a second argument:

```
var txt = new RegExp("([0-9]{4}[a-z]{1})", "i");
```

Comment: Two shortcomings: 1) constructor is used while a literal notation is preferable, 2) no anchors used that allows strings like `#$@RFWEEabcd1er45$$$$`.

Comment: @stribizhev  - Did the OP say other characters are not ok? He only said it must have 4 letters then number somewhere.

Comment: I see you translated it into *contains*. I am pretty sure OP meant *is equal to*. However, when a question is that unclear, I'd rather refrain from any more comments.